# How to check the possibility of groups union in a sequence order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following columns:
ID_group, ID_elements
For example with the following records:

```
1, 1
1, 2
2, 2
2, 4
2, 5
2, 6
3, 7
```

And I have sets of the elements, for example: 1,2,5; 1,5,2; 1,2,4; 2,7;

I need to check (true or false) that exist a common group for the pairs of adjacent elements.

For example elements:

```
1,2,5 -> true [i.e. elements 1,2 has common group 1 and elements 2,5 has common group 2]
1,5,2 -> false [i.e. 1,5 do not have a common group unlike 5,2 (but the result is false due to 1,5 - false)]
1,2,4 -> true 
2,7 -> false
```

Comment: Is this just for three elements, or does it have to work for any size set?

Comment: How are the sets represented in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need a list of pairs. We can get this by taking your set as an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), turning each element into a row with [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and then making pairs by matching each row with its previous row using [`lag`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

```
with nums as (
    select *
    from unnest(array[1,2,5]) i
)
select lag(i) over() a, i b
from nums
offset 1;

 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 5
(2 rows)
```

Then we join each pair with each matching row. To avoid counting duplicate data rows twice, we count only the distinct rows.

```
with nums as (
    select *
    from unnest(array[1,2,5]) i
), pairs as (
    select lag(i) over() a, i b
    from nums
    offset 1
)
select
    count(distinct(id_group,id_elements)) = (select count(*) from pairs)
from pairs
join foo on foo.id_group = a and foo.id_elements = b;
```

This works on any size array.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c1a8420cab2e960c7ebcbe4e9562198c)

Answer (score 1):

Your query to check if elements in a set evaluate to true or not can be done via procedures/function. Set representation can be taken as a string and then splitting it to substring then returning the required result can use a record for multiple entries.  For sql query, below is a sample that can be used as a workaround, you can try changing the below query based on your requirement.

```
    select case when ( Select count(*) 
    from ( SELECT   
     id_group, count(distinct id_elements)
   from table where
     id_group 
      in (1,2,5) 
    group by ID_group having 
    id_elements 
    in (1,2,5)) =3 ) then "true" else "false" 
    end) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern), thank you, it helped. But I have changed the condition `join foo on foo.id_group = a`, because as I understand, `a` is element's ID, not group's. I have changed the following section:

```
join foo fA on fA.id_elements = a 
join foo fB on fB.id_elements = b and fA.group_id = fB.group_id;
```